Selenium: Can not connect to the Service (OSX)
I'm trying pilot my everyday Chrome browser using Selenium and Python.
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service

service = service.Service('/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get('https://www.httpbin.org/get')

When executing this script Chrome shows up, then I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foo/bar/test-selenium.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver.get('https://www.httpbin.org/get')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/foo/bar/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Users/foo/bar/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/foo/bar/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in start
    raise WebDriverException(f"Can not connect to the Service {self._path}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

Note: I need to pilot my everyday Chrome instance, not chromedriver.
